# PIG Programming

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

How to write a PIG Query to get the count of presence of values in a field?

e.g:

Field A | Field B

20|ABC;

21|XYZ;

25|null;

99|WER;

45|null;

89|FOY;

---

Required O/P : Count of Field A = 6, Count of Field B = 4

Answer (score 8):

Pig doesn't treat the above input as `null` its basically a `chararray`, so all the built-in functions like(`is null, is not null`) will not work in this case. You need to group all the fields, filter out the null values and get the count. Can you try the below script?

**input**

```
20|ABC;
21|XYZ;
25|null;
99|WER;
45|null;
89|FOY;
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage('|') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B {
                filterNull =  FILTER A BY (f2!='null;');
                GENERATE COUNT(A.f1) AS fieldA, COUNT(filterNull.f2) AS fieldB;
              }
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(6,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find steps to follow to get the output

```
fieldcount =  load '/user/examples/stackoverflow/count.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (a:int, b:chararray); 

fieldcount1 = FOREACH fieldcount GENERATE a, REPLACE(b,';','') as b;

fieldcount2 = GROUP fieldcount1 ALL;

fieldcount3 = FOREACH fieldcount2 {
    a_cnt = FILTER fieldcount1 BY a is not null;
    b_cnt = FILTER fieldcount1 BY b is not null and b != 'null' ;
    GENERATE COUNT(a_cnt) as a_count, COUNT(b_cnt) as b_count;
}
```

Comment: The condition  "a_cnt" and the first condition of "b_cnt" will be always true at any point of time, bcoz the input doesn't contain the real null value rather than its a chararray. In this case "is not null" condition is not going to help anyway to get the expected output. Its extra condition added in the script, actually its not required, that is the reason i mentioned "is null" built function will not work in this case. If the input actually contain the real null value then no need to do all these things, just after group all, project the count function based on the column.

Answer (score 0):

please find the answer :-
my sample data is

```
003 Amit Delhi India 12000 

004 Anil Delhi India 15000

005 Deepak Delhi India 34000

006 Fahed Agra India 45000

007 Ravi Patna India 98777

008 Avinash Punjab India 120000

009 Saajan Punjab India 54000

001 Harit Delhi India 20000

002 Hardy Agra India 20000

011  Banglore
```

its all separated by space

Code is as below :-

```
A = load '/edata' using PigStorage(' ') as (eid:int,name:chararray,city:chararray,country:chararray,salary:int);

s = group A ALL ;

result = foreach s generate COUNT(A.eid),COUNT(A.name),COUNT(A.country),COUNT(A.salary);

dump result ;
```

You will get following result :-

```
(10,9,9,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**:

```
20|ABC
21|XYZ
25|null
99|WER
45|null
89|FOY
```

**Script**:

```
inputData = LOAD 'input' using PigStorage('|');
grouped_input = GROUP inputData ALL;
counts = FOREACH grouped_input GENERATE COUNT($1), COUNT($2);
dump counts;
```